# Switching between Taglist and buffer in gvim

Tags: vim, taglist

How do I can switch between Taglist bar and current buffer without mouse?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
Ctrl-w h/j/k/l
```

for moving between buffers or

```
Ctrl-w Ctrl-w
```

for going through all buffers